# Menu links jump out from pannel after zoom

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

Good evening,
I have problem with my menu links. When I see it on mobile and zoom it for text, links just jump out from pannel to next row.( http://www.abclinuxu.cz/data/prilohy/0/6/214560-img_1705-3567267490611876903.PNG ) I have set position fixed etc.. How can I force this bug? Thank you for advices!

HTML:

```
<div id="nabidka">

    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li><a href='#about'>O nás</a></li>
       <li><a href='#cenik'>Ceník</a></li>
       <li><a href='#sluzby'>Služby</a></li>
       <li><a href='#kontakt'>Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#nabidka {

width:550px;
height: 90px;

margin-left: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 5px;
float:left;

}

#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {

  list-style: none;
  line-height: 80px;

  margin: 0 auto;

}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;

  line-height: 80px;
  height:90px;

}
#cssmenu > ul {

}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {

  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: ;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #f26c4f;
}
#sipka {
position: absolute;
left: -1000px;
}
#cssmenu #menu-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see what it is supposed to look like. Try to share a link to your html file.

However, I believe the issue lies in your CSS. You are using a combination of `px` values combined with `em`. Try to put the `line-height` for `#cssmenu` in `em`, perhaps that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From a really fast look at your code, i think the issue is related to the element getting collapsed due to the "float: left".

This issue is easily fixed with .clearfix method [Clearfix snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). You fix this issue by placing the .clearfix class on the parent element  or on any parent of the elements you float.

Another simple solution, which i would not recommend is using `overflow:hidden;`

Hope this helps.